# customize the silverlight esri feature data grid form template?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

I would like to add drop down box and multi-column text box to the feature data form which pops up when i click on the feature data grid.  Instead of the regular text box i would like to replace some other controls.

```
<esri:FeatureDataForm x:Name="MyFeatureDataForm"  Style="{StaticStyle1}"  IsReadOnly="False" LabelPosition="Left" />
```

How can i achieve this customization?